# How to run pre/post job scripts on self-hosted GitHub Actions runner

Tags: windows, docker, github-actions

## Problem

I am trying to use a Windows Docker container to run GitHub Actions.

I want to run scripts before and after the job (e.g. to clean the directory).

I have successfully done this before on a computer not running docker, so I figured the same should work in docker.

## What I have tried

I found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/running-scripts-before-or-after-a-job) that you can do that using Environment Variables.
I used the following two commands in command prompt to set the environment variables.

Pre-Job Script:

```
setx ACTIONS_RUNNER_HOOK_JOB_STARTED C:\actions-runner-resources\scripts\pre-post-build\pre-run-script.ps1
```

Post-Job Script:

```
setx ACTIONS_RUNNER_HOOK_JOB_COMPLETED C:\actions-runner-resources\scripts\pre-post-build\post-run-script.ps1
```

The scripts do not run.

I have tried restarting the docker container.

I have tried restarting the actions runner service.

I am new to docker, so I am wondering if I am doing something wrong with the environment variables that does not work with docker.

How do I get the actions runner to run pre/post job scripts in docker?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely add them to your environment variable by doing this recommended method;

Inside the **actions-runner** directory, locate the **.env** file, edit it by adding your environment variable. Save and restart the runner service.

Comment: Is there a way you could build that into the dockerfile?